# How change friendly name notify twilio sms

Tags: node.js, json, twilio, sms, twilio-api

I am having some problems, I want to change the name of the sender. I mean, it is possible to assign an Alphanumeric Sender ID, I reviewed the documentation and followed the guidelines, in the response of the twilio api the name goes but when in the messages I receive it sends them to the same number. I know that it is not something due to the regulations of the country because according to the twilio documentation, it is possible. (https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) What is happening? How can I fix? Do I have to do any configuration?

[image]

**How I want the sender ID to be seen**
[image]

**As I receive the sender ID**

[image]

**UPDATING QUESTION**

Ok, the way I have structured the code is as follows:

I am working on a nodejs project, I need to send a message to multiple phone numbers so in order to do it I used the SMS notification service offered by Twilio, this is the method that was created:

```
async sendSMSAsNotify(req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {
            console.log("req.body:", req.body);
            let messageBody = req.body.body;
            console.log(messageBody);
            let numberList = req.body.toBinding;
            let extractBody = messageBody.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
            console.log(extractBody);
            var decodedStripedHtml = he.decode(extractBody);

            //console.log(decodedStripedHtml);

            //console.log(`Body: ${messageBody}`);
            var numbers = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
                numbers.push(
                    JSON.stringify({
                        binding_type: "sms",
                        address: numberList[i],
                    })
                );
            }

            const notificationOpts = {
                toBinding: numbers,
                body: decodedStripedHtml,
                title: 'MyCompany'
            };

            // console.log("numbers:", notificationOpts.toBinding);
            // console.log("body", notificationOpts.body);

            const response = await this.client.notify
                .services(process.env.SERVICE_SID_NTF)
                .notifications.create(notificationOpts);

            console.log('response', response);

            res.json({
                msg: `Message sent successfully!  ${response}`,
            });
        } catch (e) {
            throw new HttpException(HttpErrors.NOT_FOUND_ERROR, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

The `sendSMSAsNotify()` method works great, I can send the same SMS to multiple numbers. But now what I want to achieve is that every message I send shows the sender id. I didn't find how to do it in the documentation of the SMS notification service, so I tried to change it and use a very simple method to send SMS via twilio to a single number just for testing.

```
async sendSMS(sms: SMSDto) {
        try {
            return await this.client.messages.create({
                body: sms.message,
                from: 'MyCompany',
                to: sms.number,
            });
        } catch (e) {
            return e
        }
    }
```

But in neither of the two methods in which I tried to change the sender identification it did not allow me and that is what brings me here, I really need help, it is a requirement that I need to fulfill and I cannot find a way to help me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I can see your result in the screenshot has an alphanumeric sender ID ("MyCompany"). What exactly is wrong here? Are you looking to update that alpha sender ID?

Comment: I've updated the question with an image of what I want the message to look like when I send it. What I am looking for is that the name of my company appears every time I send a message, I want to change the alpha sender id, but instead of receiving the message with the name of my company I receive it with a random code. Why is this happening? Why does Twilio ignore the name I send to the Sender ID? Maybe this happens because in the body of the messages I send I've been attaching a link to my own domain and Twilio thinks it's spam so that's why it won't let me change the sender id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, while the [list of countries that support alphanumeric sender IDs does contain Honduras](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) there are further [guidelines for SMS in Honduras](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/hn/sms) that say:

> Dynamic Alphanumeric Sender IDs are not fully supported for Honduras mobile operators. Sender IDs may be overwritten with a local long code or short code outside the Twilio platform.

So, even if you set everything up as I am about to explain, it is still possible that your sender ID may be overwritten with a local long code or short code and that Twilio is unable to do anything about that.

That being said, here's how to set up for alphanumeric sender IDs.

---

Since you are using Notify to send the messages, you will have set up a [Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services) to use with Notify.

The Messaging Service controls how the SMS messages are sent out from Notify, from a pool of numbers. That pool can also contain your alphanumeric sender ID

So, to send from an alphanumeric sender ID you need to go to your *Sender Pool* within your Messaging Service and add an alpha sender.

[image: On the Sender Pool page, click the button titled "Add Senders"]

[image: A modal will appear, choose Alpha Sender in the drop down.]

Once you have the alpha sender set in your Messaging Service's pool, it will be used to send your messages out. You can even remove any long code numbers you have in the pool, if you do not plan to use them, though they are useful to fallback to if you do send to a country that doesn't support alphanumeric sender IDs.

Comment: Hello! I'm very grateful to have obtained a clear explanation, about what could be happening, really thank you very much. Now, I made the configurations that you recommended and when I tried to add a new alphanumeric identifier, it gave me a warning "Alphanumeric Sender is not enabled for this account" so what they have explained to me actually happens. It's a shame, but why is this happening?

Comment: Is it a matter of local operators? I understand Twilio's policies, but I was wondering, if it really can't be done this way, is there a way to buy a number locally in Honduras and take it to Twilio to get these types of settings?

Comment: You do need to have an upgraded account to use alphanumeric sender IDs too. Are you still on trial? If you have an upgraded account, but still see that message, then I would [contact Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to get it sorted.

Comment: Oh yes, I updated my twilio account, and even tried to get someone from support to respond to me but it was just failed attempts, that brings me here, but I will keep trying to communicate, as it is very important for me to get a direct contact

Comment: If you can share your support ticket number, I can try to follow up for you.

Comment: I just created a new ticket, maybe you can help me Ticket ID: 8384593

Comment: I can see that this is your first ticket, so I'm not sure what you were talking about when you said you tried to get someone from support to respond to you. The ticket is waiting for someone in support to get to it and when they do they will be able to help you with your alphanumeric sender ID access.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I can really promise you that with my team we tried to send tickets, and without knowing what to do we even tried to communicate with someone by mail, of course before the history of the tickets I sent did not appear and now it does. Maybe it has to do with that they were not sent, or because of the type of account I previously had. In any case, thank you very much, the ticket that I started on Saturday will be pending. Thank you

Comment: Just checked the ticket, seems your account is enabled to use alpha senders, it's just a UI issue. I actually have the same UI notice on my account, I just assumed it was slightly broken as I have various different things enabled on my account as an employee account! Press continue and finish setting up your alpha sender ID and see what happens when you send now.

Comment: Hi @philnash the Sender Pool in Messaging Service just allow only one Alpha sender id, right? And if I created an Alpha sender id, I can use it immediately, Right?  Thank you

Comment: @Jun89 yes for the first question, probably for the second question. Some countries require pre-registration of alpha senders, but most allow to use them straight away.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @philnash. I have one last consideration before I use MS. The Alpha sender Id can be duplicated or the same in multiple different message services or the same with the available Alpha sender id of another company. Do we have any validation for the name?

Comment: You can use the same ID across different services or accounts. The only validation is that it must be 11 characters or fewer and have at least one letter.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are in a country that does not [support alphanumeric sender IDs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) and that Twilio falls back on a short code then?

PS: It would be helpful if you could add a code snippet, that shows the code you run, to your question.

Comment: Hi! I updated the question with the code, maybe you can help me, the country is Honduras, according to the list it's possible, or am I wrong?